# How to create session using flask where username comes from mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, flask

```
if (username==aname or username==aemail) and userpass==apass:
            session['user'] = username
```

here aname and apass are username and password coming from database

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a contextmanager to handle database session:

```
@contextmanager
def get_db_session(aname: str, apass: str):
    connection = None

    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                            database='your_database',
                                            user=aname,
                                            password=apass)
        if connection.is_connected():
            yield connection
    except Exception as e:
        # Catch more appropriate exception
        pass    
    finally:
        if connection.is_connected():
            # Remember to close database
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
```

To create a db session:

```
with get_db_session() as session:
    # Perform tasks with your database
```

Connection is closed as soon as the code exits the context (as shown in finally block in get_db_session())

Furthermore, all database connection exceptions can be handled there.
Note: code syntax may not be correct, but you get the general idea